# How to update row in junction table for student grade

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, phpmyadmin

Here i am again.
Thank you so much for help.

Here is my Old question on how i can select and display the grade of student in a junction table.

> [Select and display all rows belonging to a specific ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206831/select-and-display-all-rows-belonging-to-a-specific-id?noredirect=1#comment97195094_55206831)

I did it successfully but now i am having trouble updating the grade in the junction table.

Here is my Example table again.

```
    "student"
-----------------------
|studentID | FullName |
-----------------------
|1234      | John    |
|1235      | Michael |
|1236      | Bryce   |

        "subject_bsit"
-----------------------------------
|subject_id| subject_name  |grade |
-----------------------------------
|    1     | Programming   |  3   |
|    2     | Networking    |  2.5 |
|    3     | Algorithm     |  1.75|
|    4     | Physical Educ |  2   |

This is the Junction table to connect the 
two now.

       "student_subject"
----------------------------
| student_id | subject_id |
----------------------------
|   1235     |      1     |
|   1235     |      2     |
|   1235     |      3     |
|   1234     |      1     |
```

And here is the query that i did. 
This is a example im trying to update the grade of  **studentID 1235** that have **subject_id = 1**

**UPDATE 3:**

```
sql = "UPDATE student_subject " & _
    " INNER JOIN subject_bsit " & _
    " ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id " & _
    " SET grade = 1 " & _
    " where student_subject.student_id='" & Txtbox.Text & "' AND student_subject.sub_id = 1"
```

The & Txtbox.Text & is where the user input the studentid don't mind it. Thank you so much im using visual studion vb.net.

And this is the exact error that i got.

> You have an error in SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
>   student_subject INNER JOIN subject_bsit ON subject_bsit.subject_id =
>   studen' at line 1

Comment: always execute your SQL command on its own before trying to put it into a string.  If it works as straight SQL then you can chop it down and make it work.  This gives you the opportunity to compartmentalize the errors - is it my SQL or is it my string syntax.  Just a tip from someone who learned this the hard way.

Comment: You still didint change the query...

Comment: @Hopper , Hi  im sorry i am not that good in database. I know i tried it and it has the same error. It works on normal Update but updating it on a junction table doesn't work. THank you

Comment: @Mihai i forgot to put the SET Grade = '1' in my recent post.  But it only output the same error. thanks

Comment: Look at my answer carefully,it`s not the same query even without SET grade.What you have it is not proper mysql syntax.

Comment: @Mihai Thank you so much. It works.  Sorry I just only started studying SQL.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wobbly ,it should be like below

```
UPDATE student_subject 
INNER JOIN subject_bsit 
ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id 
SET grade=? 
where student_subject.student_id='" & Txtbox.Text & "' AND student_subject.sub_id = 1
```

Comment: Hi sorry,  I will update my question i forgot to type the grade anyway still the same error thank you.

Comment: @Mihai  Please use Parameters in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't UPDATE student_subject.
Since there is no student_id column in your subject_bsit table you can't relate the grade to a student.

UPDATE subject_bsit
Set grade = @grade
Where subject_ID = @subject_ID

This would accomplish the same thing.

This is the schema I suggest.

**students**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| studentID   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| studentName | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**grades**

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| studentID | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| subjectID | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| grade     | decimal(3,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Two Foreign Keys

1. grades.studentID (FK) <- students.studentID (PK)
2. grades.subjectID (FK) <- subjects.subjectID (PK)

Notice the grades table has a composite key consisting of 2 fields.

**subjects**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| subjectID   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subjectName | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Please always use parameters when communicating with the database. This will help protect your database from Sql Injection.

The Using blocks close and dispose your database objects even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim query As String = "Update grades 
                           Set grade = @grade
                           Where studentId = @studentId And subjectID = @subjectID"
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.StudentConnection)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@grade", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 1
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@subjectID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 1
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

To display a students grades, add a DataGridView to your form.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim query As String = "Select st.studentName, sub.subjectName, g.grade
                            From grades g
                            Inner Join  students st  on g.studentID = st.studentID
                            Inner Join subjects sub on g.subjectID = sub.subjectID
                            Where st.studentID = @studentID;"
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.StudentConnection)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```